# Get time spent in garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'd like to know how to get the time spent in GC. I think it is possible because newrelic provides this information on jvm monitoring.
Thanks

Comment: You should provide more information. From where do you want to get the time? From within the app or is a command line tool OK? Do you want to get this information for a specific time period or maybe the average time spent per minute?

Comment: It does not really matter if it is inside the app or a cli. I'd like to know how much time was spend in GC un the last minute if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For hotspot jvm start jvm with `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` and it will start logging gc events which includes time spent

if you want to redirect it to file

```
-Xloggc:/home/someuser/app/logs/jvm/gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/community/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the information in your program, then you could do it using MXBeans. like

```
List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> list = ManagementFactory
                .getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();
        for (GarbageCollectorMXBean bean : list) {
            System.out.println(bean.getCollectionTime());
        }
```

[More Information.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `jstat` tool provided with your JVM distribution. Run `jstat -gc <pid>`. It will display the following values relevant for your question:

- In the `GCT` column: the total number of seconds spent in GC since the JVM started
- In the `FGCT` column: the total number of seconds spent in *Full* GC since the JVM started
- In the `YGCT` column: the total number of seconds spent in *Young Gen* GC since the JVM started